# Best method for dealing with unmatched regex search in python?

Tags: python, regex

Currently, I have some code that uses try/except to skip running code on file paths that do not match some regex. The substring that is extracted with the "group" functionality is used later in the code as well.

```
for path in pathsList:
    try: 
        subfolder = re.search("\.(\w+)\.\d+\.\w+$", path).group(1)
    except AttributeError: 
        subfolder = None

    if subfolder:
        #do stuff with the extracted 'subfolder' substring
```

But I feel like there is potentially a cleaner way to do this. Assuming that I have to stick to regex (my real use case is a bit more complicated so I can't use simpler string/file/path parsing libraries), is this the best way to go about it?

Comment: `re.search()` with return `None` if it does not match anything so check for `None` instead of try/catch

Comment: Were you trying to use a `try/except` block here solely to follow the EAFP principle, or you did you just not know any other ways? If the former is the case, then I'd have to disagree. More often than not, when followed the EAFP  principle provides cleaner, more idiomatic code. However, you shouldn't follow every standard dogmatically. There are valid exceptions- and this is one of them. As the answer below states,  using  LBYL would result in cleaner code here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I simply didn't think of the much better solution proposed below. I wasn't intending to stick to try/except block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression which returns *no matches* evaluates to `False`, so you can simply do:

```
search = re.search("\.(\w+)\.\d+\.\w+$", path)
if search:
     subfolder = search.group(1)
```

---

[The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) states **exactly** this!

> Since match() and search() return `None` when there is no match, you can test whether there was a match with a simple if statement:
>
> ```
> match = re.search(pattern, string)
> if match:
>     process(match)
> ```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. I understand the question probably looked dumb but this simple answer somehow slipped my mind.